# jQuery - Set min-height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is probably really easy for most of you. But I'm in need of a small snippet that looks up the current height of a div (the div has a dynamic height based on the content inside it)
and then set that value in the css class's min-height value.

Basically what this means is that I want this container to have it's min-height to be the exact same value as it's current height. This is probably a quick one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just a proof of concept!

```
     // attend for dom ready
    $(function() {
        // hide .foo before we get it's height
        $('.foo').hide();
        // get the height, also the one mentioned below is a good one!
        var foo_height = $('.foo').height();
        // see if the actual height respect our needs! esample 180px
        if ( foo_height > 180 ) {
            // set the height and show it!
            //$('.foo').css('height', foo_height + 'px').show(); OR try
            $('.foo').height( foo_height ).show();
        } else {
            //do something else here
            }
});
```

this should work as expected!

Answer (score 69):

If I understand you correctly, you could do the following:

```
$(".foo").css("min-height", function(){ 
    return $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Yes this is working :)
The reason I'm asking is because I've got a div with no height specified is emptied before it's populated by other content. Making the whole container dynamic in size based on what's in it. In this small gap between no content and content, the div shrinks to it's min-height before growing to it's needed size. The downside here is that the div doesn't go down in size dynamically, only upwards. Do you know of a good way of going around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var elt = document.getElementById("<%= this.your_element_id.ClientID %>");
elt.style.minHeight = elt.clientHeight + 'px';
```