# make jquery use min-height not just height

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code:

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(function(){
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn){
            tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
        }
    });
    if (tallestcolumn <= 1000) {
        columns.height(tallestcolumn + 4);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setEqualHeight($("#main-content-bottom-bg  > div"));
});
```

I know its probably simple, but I just cannot figure out what I give. I would think something like this:

```
columns.minheight(tallestcolumn + 4);
```

Thanks.

Comment: He wants to change the `min-height` for some elements. I thought it was quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function :

```
 function setEqualHeight(columns){
      var tallestcolumn = 0;
      columns.each(function(){
           currentHeight = $(this).height();
           if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn){
                tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
           }
      });
      if (tallestcolumn <= 1000) {
           columns.css("min-height",(tallestcolumn + 4)+"px");
      }
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
     setEqualHeight($("#main-content-bottom-bg  > div"));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Since you were earliest I'll give you the win. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Almost... try:

```
columns.css('min-height', (tallestcolumn + 4) + 'px');
```

Similar to: [jQuery - Set min-height of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750892/jquery-set-min-height-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
columns.css('min-height',(tallestcolumn + 4)+'px');
```

Comment: awesome thanks. I knew it would be something easy enough, but my brain was just fried. Thanks again!