# jQuery css min-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simple.. I'm running into a syntax error. `$('#container').css('min-height', '360');` doesn't set a rule, but `$('#container').css('height', '360');` does.

Help?

Comment: A similiar min-height question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750892/jquery-set-min-height-of-div

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First try:

```
$('#container').css('min-height', '360px');
```

Otherwise try

```
$('#container').attr('style','min-height:360px;other-styles');
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
$('#container').css('min-height', '360px');
```

Comment: The property is actually min-height

Comment: @Paolo -  thanks,  I was going to back and remove that after -  I had to include it because of the minimum character requirement for edits

Answer (score 2):

Got to this question looking for `jQuery.css` when passing an object literal.

With jQuery 2 I could do:

```
$(selector).css({minHeight:"20px"});
```

Now I can pass a bunch of things at once:

```
$(selector).css({
  minHeight:"20px",
  minWidth:"20px",
  backgroundColor:"yellow",
});
```