# How to get the correct Bootstrap Jumbotron height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple example of a bootstrap jumbotron split into 2 parts. The left part contains some text, the right part contains an image:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="col-md-8"><h1><b>My WebSite Jumbotron!</b></h1>
    <p>This page would be great if the jumbotron would be higher.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

See also [my bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/iUnNYWqHok). For some reason the height of the background of the Jumbotron is not large enough to contain the text and the image. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a little late, but I believe your solution will be Jumbotron and container-fluid

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron container-fluid">
<div style="clear:both;">
  Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Vivamus euismod mauris. Aenean massa. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis.

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Proin magna. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor.

Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Aliquam lobortis. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Nulla porta dolor.

Quisque id mi. Nunc nonummy metus. Nullam quis ante. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl.
  </div>
  <br/>
<div style="clear:both;">
  Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Vivamus euismod mauris. Aenean massa. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis.

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Proin magna. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor.

Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Aliquam lobortis. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Nulla porta dolor.

Quisque id mi. Nunc nonummy metus. Nullam quis ante. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl.
  </div>
```

Comment: Although the css class "container-fluid" worked for the simplified example, the height of the jumbotron in my real website was still too small after this change. This appeared to be a bug in Bootstrap 3.0. After an upgrade to Bootstrap 3.2 the problem was gone.

Answer (score 8):

I have tested this and it works.

You can edit your jumbotron div tag to include the css class container.

Example:

```
<div class="jumbotron container">
```

Comment: Thanks Tray. This is much better, but this will make the Jumbotron smaller.

Comment: +1 very good suggestion, I had a similar problem where I wanted the jumbotron to dynamically resize, having an image set to its background and now using `class="jumbotron img-responsive container"` and setting the `height:auto` I get the desired effect, thank you for the nudge in the right direction. I don't even have to worry about the text now, it sizes automatically and equally vertical/horizontal.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add this to your stylesheet.

```
.jumbotron { min-height: 600px; }
```

Also you can add an extra class to your body like `<body class="test">` and use this CSS

```
test.jumbotron { min-height: 600px; }
```

You can adjust the `min-height` to fit your content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but it forces me to adjust the min-height each time I change the text of my Jumbotron. Is there a less ad hoc way to solve this?

Comment: Here is a likely solution to dynamically adjust min-height based on the content. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750892/jquery-set-min-height-of-div

Answer (score 0):

It may only apply to Bootstrap 4 but this solved it for me...

```
<div class="jumbotron-fluid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that no answer is the correct since all the container classes have other properties too so the most clean should be `clearfix` in this way:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-8"><h1><b>My WebSite Jumbotron!</b></h1>
<p>This page would be great if the jumbotron would be higher.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
<img src="//placehold.it/300" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```