# Set min-height of div to the height of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

My question is along the lines of this question: [jQuery - Set min-height of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750892/jquery-set-min-height-of-div) but with a slight alternation.

I'm using a dropdown menu in Wordpress, along with RoyalSlider. The slider div has a changing height value, depending on the browser size.

I think I'm having a bit of strange outcome though. I'm using the code that was given as the most popular answer in the linked question, and changed the elements to match with my code:

```
$("#menu-main-menu > li.menu-parent-item > ul.sub-menu").css("min-height", function(){ 
    return $("#new-royalslider-1").height();
});
```

From how I read this, this will set the min-height of the ul.sub-menu to whatever the height value of the RoyalSlider div is.

Although, it's always returned as 400px, no matter what size the browser window is.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: The height is presumably only set on load of the page. If the `#new-royalslider-1` element size changes on resize of the window, then you need to also run this code on the `resize` event of the window.

Comment: Also try `.css("min-height", $("#new-royalslider-1").height() )`, it's just simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That would make sense, but the strange thing is even if I re-size the window, and then refresh.. the value is still always 400px. That should change shouldn't it? Would you be able to post an answer with some example code to demonstrate the `resize` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery's `outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) function to get the *"current computed height"* of your slider, and execute it on load and on resize events:

```
function resizeMenu(){
    $("#menu-main-menu > li.menu-parent-item > ul.sub-menu").css("min-height",
        $("#new-royalslider-1").outerHeight()
    );
}

// Do this on load and on resize
$(window).load(resizeMenu).resize(resizeMenu);
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

**Edit**: If you want to substract 40px to the height, you can just do `....outerHeight()-40`. [Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vLLguuwv/1/)

Comment: Hmm, strangely the div is still setting at 400px, no matter how much the window is resized. I noticed the JS code in your fiddle, is different to the pasted above.. will that make a difference?

Comment: @Lee In this case, the order should not make a difference. When and how are you executing this? If you do `$("#new-royalslider-1").outerHeight()`, you get 400px?

Comment: I don't understand 'if you do'. What am I looking for? If you m ean, put this into the console in Inspector, I get an uncaught type error: undefined is not a function

Comment: Your updated code seems to work okay now, I still need to do some tweaking, but I think this is what I'm after. Thanks alot. Just one question though, am I able to easily minus 40px from whatever the outerHeight result is?

Comment: @Lee sorry, yeah, I meant to say `console.log($("#new-royalslider-1").outerHeight())`. The difference with simply `height()` is that it also includes the padding and the border. Maybe that's what you need to tweak. You can also look at `innerHeight()` which includes the padding, but not the border. I'll edit my answer about the `minus 40px`.

Comment: It's not to do with padding or anything, it's because the menu drops down from the main navigation at the top (which is 40px high), and the slider is actually behind that, but right up against the top of the browser.